# Mercurial strange hg init issue

Tags: mercurial

very new in Mercurial. I have noticed that my hg init is not working. let me explain it:

when I give this command hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hello my-hello ,then, my_hello folder is created with all the(2) files. then I delete .hg folder from my_hello. then I initialize this folder with hg init. it is initialized.

But after initializing that, when I go to clone the folder with hg clone my_hello new_my_hello, it just make the .hg folder in the new_my_hello folder, not the other files it should.

and for all the tries I am getting this problem. please help.

I am using windows 7 64 bit. My Mercurial is also 64 bit.

Comment: Why are you deleting the .hg folder that comes with the clone? By doing this, you are losing all of the repository history, and your new repo (after your `hg init` will be incompatible with the repo you cloned it from 9.e. you won't be able to push changes back)

Comment: thats not the actual point. i am deleting folder to test whether the hg init works or not. and I find hg init not working , when I go to init has the data after running hg tip: changeset:   -1:000000000000. 
tag:         tip
user:
date:        Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, I would say it is working as it should, see my answer below for what you're missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: untracked files are not included in a clone.

If you first remove the .hg metadata directory and reinitialize a new one, it will no longer track any files; no files are added by default on init. So when you clone it, you get a clone of an empty repository. Like so:

```
$ hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hello my-hello
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 2 changesets with 2 changes to 2 files
updating to branch default
2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ cd my-hello
$ ls
Makefile  hello.c
$ hg st --all
C Makefile
C hello.c
```

Above is a perfectly normal copy of the repo with no modified files.

```
$ rm -rf .hg
$ hg st --all
abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
```

Now there is no repo any more.

```
$ hg init
$ hg st --all
? Makefile
? hello.c
```

Now there is one, but it no longer tracks the files, hence the "?".

```
$ hg clone . ../new-my-hello
updating to branch default
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ cd ../new-my-hello
$ hg st --all
$ ls
```

The clone does not include untracked files, so the two "?-files" from "my-hello" are not cloned.

Answer (score 3):

You create a repository by running `hg init`, which you've already done. However, you have not yet started tracking any files. To do this, you must explicitly tell hg which files to track with `hg add file1 file2 ...`. Alternately, you can add all files by calling `hg addremove`. After this, you need to add those files to the repo via `hg commit`.

Once you do this in the original repo, in your new_my_hello, you will be able to pull these changes from my_hello by calling `hg pull`, and in order to get the latest versions of those files, follow with an `hg update`.

All that being said, I am certain that no good can come from deleting your existing .hg folder.

A very helpful resource for learning hg workflows that does a better job of explaining why you weren't getting what you thought you were getting is http://hginit.com